# Unable to complete request. [Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized ]

Tags: http-headers, vimeo, vimeo-api

Am I getting that error while trying to upload my videos via vimeo API. I dont know what is causing this for I had configured everything and was working well and staying for a while without uploading now when I came back to upload I cannot. my membership just auto renewed so its **active**.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

About 2 years go, Vimeo removed api.vimeo.com cert pinning from all the Vimeo API libraries to get ready for the certificate expiration in early March 2023.

See https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/pull/546 and https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/pull/288

Please update your SDK version to one one that has been released in the last 2 years.

If that's not an option, see threads here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/issues/329 for how to use a different certificate.